# Single input instrumentation amplifier

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

I have an instrumentation amplifier, INA 126. I am using it to amplify the physiological signals from the eye movement. The circuit I have constructed has 2 stages: 1st stage has INA 126 with a gain of 1000 and the 2nd stage has another INA 126 also with a gain of 1000.

My question is that the 1st stage only has one output so where do I connect this output?I have tried connecting it to Vin+ and grounded the Vin- of the 2nd INA 126, is this the right thing to do? I have read the datasheet and it does not mention of having one input only.

P.S
I am using dual supply.. +12V and -12V and I have connected the Ref pin of the INA126 to ground as mentioned in the datasheet.

Comment: That sounds fine.

Comment: So theoretically the Vout from the 2nd stage is Vout=Gain(Vin+) right?

Comment: There's no reason to use another instrumentation amp as the second stage - use a regular opamp instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that. There's not much point in using an instrumentation amplifier when the input is single-ended but there's no harm in it (other than to your pocketbook and likely inferior noise performance). Since you're preceding it with a gain of 1000, noise is not going to be an issue, so just cost.

I do hope your circuit is AC coupled, otherwise you're going to have problems- the 250uV offset of the INA126 multiplied by 10^6 is 250V which will rail the output amplifier.

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance sir but how do you do AC coupling?

Comment: @Herbert One method is to provide a resistance to ground for the bias current and connect a capacitor to the input voltage. You can do that between stages. The input might be a bit trickier- [here](http://www.seekic.com/uploadfile/ic-circuit/2014520205853829.jpg) is one method.

Comment: @herbert, It's probably enough to put the AC coupling between the first and second stage.  There a simple RC will be fine... You need to know what frequencies you are interested in... 0.1 uF with 10k ohm to ground starts responding above ~ 100 Hz.  If your signal is at or near DC you may have to change your approach.

Comment: @Herbert: I strongly recommend that you do not proceed. You plan to use this device attached to a human, but you don't even know AC coupling? *that is not good* My feeling is that you should learn a lot about electronics before progressing.....